# How to run a parents method twice

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I'm Making a game which uses a parent to run an attack class as shown below

```
public String attack(int damage, int extradamage, String type) {

    int hitpossibility;

    hitpossibility = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    if (type.compareTo("Ranged") == 0) {
        weaponnoise = "twang!";

    }else{
    weaponnoise = "swing!";
    }

    if (chancetohit >= hitpossibility) {
        for (int x = 0; x < damage; x++) {
            result = result + (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        }
        result = result + extradamage;
         return weaponnoise + " The " + name + " did " + +result + " damage";


    }
    return weaponnoise +"The " +name+" missed!";
}
```

I have multiple different weapons which i want to use and have succeded in this however i have a dagger which i would like to attack twice per turn instead of once like the others. This is the class which i use to set the daggers damage values:

```
public class Dagger extends Blade {

public Dagger() {
    super();
    damage = 1;
    extradamage = -1;
    chancetohit = 75;
}

public String attack(int damage, int extradamage, String type) {

    return super.attack(damage, extradamage, type);
}
```

I then have a class that runs it and currently it does this:

```
    for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
        System.out.println(pointy.attack(pointy.damage, pointy.extradamage, pointy.getType()));
        monsterhealth = monsterhealth - pointy.result;
        System.out.println(monsterhealth);
        pointy.result = 0;
    }
```

Instead of it printing the attack twice, i want it to attack twice on the same line. I was wondering what i can change in the dagger class which would allow me to do so.
Any help is of course appreciated thank you!

Comment: Just call the member function twice?

Comment: Where do i call it, the dagger class or the main?

Comment: OK thanks bro! worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is an explanation of @Arnav 's comments. Here `Dagger` is a sub-class of the main `weapon` class and you want to invoke super-class' `attack` twice when the attack method of `Dagger` is called.

For this you need to call `super.attack` twice from `Dagger` attack method:

```
public class Dagger extends Blade {

public Dagger() {
super();
damage = 1;
extradamage = -1;
chancetohit = 75;
}

public String attack(int damage, int extradamage, String type) {
   String result1 = super.attack(damage, extradamage, type);
   String result2 =super.attack(damage, extradamage, type);
   return // You can return result1 or result2 based on your requirement
}
```

Note: I deleted my earlier answer, because this approach is better than the other one.

Comment: Thanks alot man, looks like all that rep is deserved. worked perfectly :)